# How can I print multiple values of the same key from SimpleIni

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ini

**The ini file:**

```
user = abc
user = def
user = ghi
user = xyz
```

**The code:**

```
CSimpleIniCaseW ini;
ini.SetUnicode();
ini.LoadFile("myapp.ini");

CSimpleIniCaseW::TNamesDepend values;
ini.GetAllValues(L"", L"user", values);
values.sort(CSimpleIniCaseW::Entry::LoadOrder());

CSimpleIniCaseW::TNamesDepend::const_iterator i;

for (i = values.begin(); i != values.end(); ++i)
   std::wcout << i->pItem << L"\n";
```

It prints only xyz. How do I get the other values? I need to insert them into a vector before passing it to another function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable multi-key first.

http://code.jellycan.com/simpleini-doc/html/class_c_simple_ini_templ.html#c3cfaf072a64f960bdcb7ddf2edc52b6

```
CSimpleIniCaseW ini;
ini.SetUnicode();
ini.SetMultiKey()
...
```